# How to pass the yytext from the lex file to yacc?

Tags: yacc, bison, lex

Please i am facing a simple problem.. here is the issue,
In my lex file i have something similiar to:

```
char *ptr_String;

"name = "  { BEGIN sName; }

<sName>.+   {
          ptr_String = (char *)calloc(strlen(yytext)+1, sizeof(char));
              strcpy(ptr_String, yytext);
              yylval.sValue = ptr_String;
              return NAME;
    }
```

Now in my Yacc file i have something similar to:

```
stmt_Name:
    NAME
    {
        /*Now here i need to get the matched string of <sName>.+ and measure it's length. */
        /*The aim is simply outputing the name to the screen and storing the length in a global variable.
    }
    ;
```

Please any suggestions? 
Thanks so much for all your time and help.

Comment: See near duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519082/how-can-i-send-the-yyleng-of-a-matched-string-from-lex-to-yacc) (asking about `yyleng` instead of `yytext`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Revised question

The value on the Yacc stack is controlled by YYSTYPE or `%union`.  Use YYSTYPE when the type information is simple; use `%union` when it is complex.

One of my grammars contains:

```
struct Token
{
    int      toktype;
    char    *start;
    char    *end;
};
typedef struct Token Token;

#define YYSTYPE Token
```

For a variety of reasons (not necessarily good ones), my grammar uses a hand-crafted lexical analyzer instead of Lex.

In the grammar rules, you refer to items like NAME in your example as `$1` (where the actual number depends on where the token appears in the list of tokens or terminals that make up the rule).

For example (same grammar):

```
disconnect
    :   K_DISCONNECT K_CURRENT
        { conn->ctype = CONN_CURRENT; }
    |   K_DISCONNECT K_ALL
        { conn->ctype = CONN_ALL; }
    |   K_DISCONNECT K_DEFAULT
        { conn->ctype = CONN_DEFAULT; }
    |   K_DISCONNECT string
        { conn->ctype = CONN_STRING;
          set_connection(conn, $2.start, $2.end);
        }
    ;
```

And:

```
load
    :   K_LOAD K_FROM opt_file_pipe string load_opt_list K_INSERT
        {
            set_string("load file", load->file, sizeof(load->file),
                       $4.start, $4.end);
            load->stmt = $6.start;
        }
    ;
```

I don't know whether seeing the outline of the hand-crafted `yylex()` helps; in the grammar, it is a function in the same file as `yyparse()`.

```
static const char *c_token;     /* Where to start next token search */

static int yylex(void)
{
    char        buffer[MAX_LEXTOKENLENGTH];
    const char *start;

    if (c_token == 0)
        abort();

    if (bare_filename_ok)
        start = scan_for_filename(c_token, &c_token);
    else
        start = sqltoken(c_token, &c_token);

    yylval.start = CONST_CAST(char *, start);
    yylval.end = CONST_CAST(char *, c_token);
    if (*start == '\0')
    {
        yylval.toktype = 0;
        return yylval.toktype;
    }
    set_token(buffer, sizeof(buffer), start, c_token);
#ifdef YYDEBUG
    if (YYDEBUGVAR > 1)
        printf("yylex(): token = %s\n", buffer);
#endif /* YYDEBUG */

    /* printf("yylex(): token = %s\n", buffer); */
    if (isalpha((unsigned char)buffer[0]) || buffer[0] == '_')
    {
        Keyword  kw;
        Keyword *p;
        kw.keyword = buffer;
        p = (Keyword *)bsearch(&kw, keylist, DIM(keylist), sizeof(Keyword),
                                kw_compare);    /*=C++=*/
        if (p == 0)
            yylval.toktype = S_IDENTIFIER;
        else
            yylval.toktype = p->token;
    }
    else if (buffer[0] == '\'')
    {
        yylval.toktype = S_SQSTRING;
    }
    else if (buffer[0] == '"')
    {
        yylval.toktype = S_DQSTRING;
    }
    else if (isdigit((unsigned char)buffer[0]))
    {
        yylval.toktype = S_NUMBER;
    }
    else if (buffer[0] == '.' && isdigit((unsigned char)buffer[1]))
    {
        yylval.toktype = S_NUMBER;
    }
```

...various single-character symbols recognized...

```
    else if (buffer[0] == ':')
    {
        assert(buffer[1] == '\0');
        yylval.toktype = C_COLON;
    }
    else
    {
        yylval.toktype = S_ERROR;
    }
    return yylval.toktype;
}
```

#### Original question

The variable is normally a global variable - your Yacc code uses one of two possible declarations:

```
extern char *yytext;    /* Correct for Flex */
extern char yytext[];   /* Correct for traditional Lex */
```

Which of those is correct depends on how your version of Lex defines it.

If you want to add a length (perhaps `yytextlen`), then you can define such a variable and have every return from `yylex()` ensure that `yytextlen` is set.  Alternatively, you can arrange for your grammar to call `wwlex()`, and your `wwlex()` simply does:

```
int wwlex(void)
{
    int rc = yylex();
    yytextlen = strlen(yytext);
    return rc;
}
```

Or you can arrange for Lex to generate code with the rename, and have Yacc continue to call `yylex()` and you provide the code above as `yylex()` and have it call the renamed Lex function.  Either way works.

Comment: thanks for your reply! please can you take a look at my edited version?

Comment: You can avoid use of strlen(yytext) because lex and flex define yyleng which is the length of yytext string.

Comment: @VGE: oh, thank you.  I'd forgotten that detail.  In that case, of course, the chicanery with the function names isn't necessary.